# Error when creating vector in python from text file

Tags: python, nlp

I want to import data from text file and make vector space representation out of words:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input="file")
f = open('D:\\test\\17.txt')
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit(f)
bag_of_words = vectorizer.transform(f)
print(bag_of_words)
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit(f)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 776, in fit
self.fit_transform(raw_documents)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 804, in fit_transform
self.fixed_vocabulary_)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 739, in _count_vocab
for feature in analyze(doc):
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 236, in <lambda>
tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 110, in decode
doc = doc.read()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which line is the error from?

Comment: Edited post for full error report.

Answer (score 0):

The `vectorizer.fit` method expects an iterable of file or string objects (not a single file object), hence you should have `vectorizer.fit([f])`.

In addition, you cannot reuse the `f` in the second call to `vectorizer.transform` (because the file has been read at that moment). What you probably want to do is the following:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(input="file")
f = open('D:\\test\\17.txt')
bag_of_words = vectorizer.fit_transform([f])
```